# JSON Blob into SQL Server

Tags: python, sql, sql-server

I have data from a web API that I want to store in a SQL database. Each record in the web API looks like this:

```
>>> inci[1]
>>> Out[47]: 
{'@odata.etag': 'W/"97914784"',
 x
```

Comment: JSON should probably be `nvarchar(max)`. If the property names are fixed you can read into proper column using `OPENJSON`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That query is invalid.  Should be of the form `INSERT INTO TableName(Column1, Column2) VALUES (?,?)`, so something like:

```
 cur.execute("""INSERT INTO IncidentBLOB(IncidentBLOB) VALUES (?)""", json.dumps(incident))
```

Comment: Your result wans't working at first, but then I changed the column type to nvarchar instead of varBinary and it now works. Thank you for your help!